# Updating YouTube iframe properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, iframe, youtube

I would like to edit the iframe properties () of all the Youtube video links which are stored on my database in a table called "Product" in a field called "FullDescription". I want to change all my Youtube videos iframe properties from iframe width="640" height="360" to iframe width="830" height="400". I was thinking if I could run an sql code on my database to change the iframe properties of all the video links stored in the database? How can I do this? Please help.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: `SET {yourColumn} = REPLACE({YourColumn},'iframe width="640" height="360"','iframe width="830" height="400"')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE` for replacing iframe values in update statement

```
UPDATE Product
 SET FullDescription = REPLACE(FullDescription,'iframe width="640" height="360"','iframe width="830" height="400"')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it actually worked. Keep up the good work helping more amateurs like me. :-)